# DISTINCT - download the content again

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is how I should use distinct to download the content again.

[image]

Here at pictures VISR it to the download content 3 times, but I only want it 1 time in total

what is the problem is that it does not pick all of them, but I only want it to pick up only one of time, which means that it only need to download one time by title and simultaneously username.

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id WHERE fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC";
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($fornavn, $efternavn, $id, $title);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <tr class="postbox">
        <td class="beskedinfo">
            <p><?php echo $fornavn . " " . $efternavn;?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><?php echo $title;?></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Slet</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Your query includes  other columns in the `SELECT` list, and the `DISTINCT` is applied over all columns, so this may not be a distinct set. If you do not intend to use the others, leave them out of the `SELECT` list.

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the ENTIRE row. If any of the fields OTHER than your two "can't repeat" contain unique data, then they're distinct and WILL be shown. You probably want `group by fra, titel` instead.

Comment: @MarcB its not work for me, i have try `SELECT DISTINCT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id WHERE fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? GROUP BY fms_bruger.title` and `SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id WHERE fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? GROUP BY fms_bruger.title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY not DISTINCT to get the grouping of the title field.

```
SELECT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title 
FROM fms_bruger 
INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id 
WHERE fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? 
GROUP BY fms_opslagpm.title 
ORDER BY fms_opslagpm.datotid DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT` does exactly what it says: it selects distinct rows.

You include `id` in the columns. I'm pretty sure IDs will be unique, therefore all rows are `DISTINCT`.

Consider removing the `DISTINCT` keyword and adding a `` GROUP BY `fms_bruger`.`title` `` clause. This is an extension to the SQL standard which will return an arbitrary row for each unique title.

Comment: i have try its here: `SELECT DISTINCT fms_bruger.fornavn, fms_bruger.efternavn, fms_opslagpm.id, fms_opslagpm.title FROM fms_bruger INNER JOIN fms_opslagpm ON fms_bruger.id=fms_opslagpm.fra_id WHERE fms_opslagpm.til_id = ? GROUP BY fms_bruger.title` and its not work for me.

Comment: Did you miss the part where I said "removing the `DISTINCT` keyword"?